# MSDN sample code not working: BusyIndicator not found

Tags: silverlight

I downloaded the source code of
http://silverlight.net/learn/videos/silverlight-videos/twitter-search-monitor/#video

Visual Studio 2010 converted it to SL4. When running it complains

> ```
> Error 3   The type or namespace name 'BusyIndicator' does not exist in the
> ```
>
> namespace 'System.Windows.Controls'
>   (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\tutorials_dotnet\silverlight\HDI-Silverlight-source-TwitterSearchApp_CS\TwitterSearchMonitor\obj\Debug\Views\Search.g.cs    38  42  TwitterSearchMonitor

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `BusyIndicator` is not found in the Silverlight SDK, its in the [Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/43528) which you need download and install.

Once installed add a reference to the `System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit` dll.

Add this namespace alias to the page using the BusyIndicator:-

```
xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"
```

You then use toolkit: alias to define it:-

```
<toolkit:BusyIndicator x:Name="busyIndicator>
    <!-- your page content -->
</toolkit:BusyIndicator>
```